# How can I figure out what serial port communication protocol is a software using?

Tags: serial-communication, protocol

I'm working to adapt an stress excercise test software so that it can work with a treadmill that uses a different communication protocol.

The communicate via a RS232 cable, with a USB-RS232 adapting device on the laptop end.

I have created a pair of virtual ports using com0com and have written a program in VB (using Visual Studio) that can open, read and write on the virtual ports. The purpose being that the program can work as a translator.

I have the treadmill protocol but not the software one, so I'm trying to listen to what the software tells to the virtual port and figure out what protocol it's using.

Is this option viable? Are there any further reading material / software I could use?

The only messages I got sof far were:

"?" when first running the test

"ìù 015ñ 000" when I set the treadmill on/off

If I don't answer, the software displays the message "treadmill failed". If I send any array of characters, it doesn't display the message and appears to start the test.

Comment: The best way to understand a communication protocol is to examine all traffic in hex, not in ASCII